# Import .jar file, poorly documented

Tags: java, import, jar, classpath

I know there are many related questions, but after reading at least 5 of them, I still feel many questions remain unanswered. 
[This jar file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsap/) is a generic argument parser for java programs, such that you will use less time writing arg parsers for each program, and instead use this. Although the program [is well documented](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/doc/index.html), a programmer like me who still has not used external .jar files, finds it odd that there is no documentation whatsoever about how I should import this(what classes etc).

So I know that I need to put the .jar file somehow in my classpath. And then probably run some additional commands when compiling my program. But how do I find out what to import from the .jar file?

Thanks in advance, and bear with me. I am an import-noob.

Comment: Did you even read my post? I clearly state that the docs do not provide this information.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said "the program is well documented,"

Comment: I don't assume I should be telling people how to use Java (covered many times elsewhere) when I write my documentation, only what is specific to my library.

Comment: You should note, how you do this depends on your build system. Java command line, ant, maven, gradle, Java 9 modules. All these are different and it's not worth repeating how to use all these.

Comment: "a programmer like me who still has not used external .jar files," so then you can google how to do that.

Comment: You are using someones elses hard work, for free, but complaining that they haven't explained the basics to you and you can't be bothered googling it but when someone tries to point out you really should be able to work that out you think it's the person trying to help you which has the problem.

Comment: Cry me a river.

Comment: I am not worried. This will happen to you one day when you try to help someone and you might remember this moment.

Comment: @Koen Alright try answering 10k java questions for people mostly of little experience then say that.

Comment: My suggestion to you is; when someone throws insults because they can't express themselves with argument, you have to be the adult in the room. My point is, everyone has to start some where and the best place to start is doing a little research for yourself. I hope for your sake, you will take on board one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Importing classes**

`import`ing the classes is symply done by `import package.subpackage.Classname;`

**Using libraries in Eclipse:**

To add the .jar file to your libraries, you better use a proper IDE (interpreting your question your are using a texteditor). I recommend [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org).

- Create a folder in your projects folder in the workspace called "lib"
  (or anything that suggests it contains your libraries)
- Move the .jar file inside the "lib" folder
- Right click on your Java project and
  select "Preferences"
- Select "Java Build Path" in the appearing window (menu on the left)
- Go to "Libraries" (menu on the top)
- Select "Add JARS..." and select your .jar from the "lib" folder
- You should now see the library listed under "Jars and class folders on the build path" Hit "Apply" and "Ok".

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the classes you want to use just like any other program. If you want to know which classes you need to read the documentation or use you IDE to add the imports for you.

If you were to cut and paste the program into an IDE it would be able to work out the imports for you however, if you don't have an IDE you need to read the javadoc http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/doc/javadoc/index.html which lists the packages you need for each class.

Adding a JAR is the same for every JAR so I guess they assumed this knowledge is covered elsewhere. When writing documentation, some knowledge has to be assumed or you would have to start with step 1) turn on your computer 2) wait for it to boot up ....

Comment: 3) procrastinate on stackoverflow